# How to delete duplicate records using Sub query without using primary key

Tags: sql-server-2005

Here is an example of the data to query:

```
| ID |  NAME | MARKS |
|----|-------|-------|
|  0 | Fazal |    89 |
|  1 | Fazal |    89 |
|  2 | Fazal |    89 |
|  3 | Fazal |    89 |
|  4 | Fazal |    89 |
|  5 | Fazal |    89 |
```

Comment: which record do you want to have left over?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove duplicate rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows) see the second answer using `ROW_NUMBER`